# how to find the largest and smallest value in a string

Tags: php, arrays, string, sorting

Hi I have a string and I want to find about the smallest and the largest value from this string and store in a variable.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 21,50
)
```

Comment: largest... as in amount of characters or numeric values? Is (21,50) a string or you want to split on comma and get from those values?

Comment: Do you have an actual array or is this a string? Either way, you probably want to put the values into an array and then use `max()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [max](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) and [min](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) function.

```
$arr = ['21,50'];
echo max(explode(',',$arr[0])); // 50
echo min(explode(',',$arr[0])); // 21
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string $a, then you can explode it, to get an array and then you can use the build in function [min()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.min.php) and [max()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.max.php)

```
$a = "21,50";
$arr = explode($a);
$maxValue = max($arr);
$minValue = min($arr);
```

You can also explode an array key to achieve this.

```
$myArr = array("21,50");
$tmpArr = explode($myArr[0]);
$maxVal = max($tmpArr);
$minVal = min($tmpArr);
```